# How to check that a string follows a format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to check if a value of the string variable follows the format `x.y.z` i.e

```
 version = "1.0.5" -- True
    version ="2.2" -- False
```

How to do this in python?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/

Comment: To check string s for x.y.z you can use the expression `True if re.search(r'\"(\d+\.){2}\d+\"', s) else False`

Comment: maybe if len(version.split('.')) == 3: would do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments sugegsted, the best solution is to use regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]")
print(True if pattern.match("1.0.5") != None else False)
```

**Output:**

```
True
```